# RAM requirements for matrix processing

Tags: python, matrix

So I'm designing a matrix for a computer vision project and believe I have one of my calculations wrong. Unfortunately, I'm not sure where it's wrong.

I was considering creating a matrix that was 100,000,000 x 100,000,000 with each 'cell' containing a single integer (1 or 0).  If my calculations are correct, it would take  9.53674316 × 10^9 MB. Is that correct?!?

My next question is, if it IS correct, are there ways to reduce memory requirements to a more realistic level while still keeping the matrix the same size?  Of course, there is a real possibility I won't actually need a matrix that size but this is absolute worse case scenario (as put forth by a friend).  The size seems ridiculous to me since we'd be covering such a small distance at a time.

Thanks1
Anthony

Comment: It's impossible to answer without knowing more about your goals.  Is the matrix sparse?  Can it be generated programmatically?  What processing do you intend to do on this matrix?

Comment: Your calculations seem correct, but beware that they assume you actually use a single bit per cell, have no alignment, no padding, no metadata, no per-row/-colum data.

Comment: 'single integer (1 or 0)."?  Do you mean a single "bit"?  A single integer is 32 bits (on many computers).  When you entered `100000000* 100000000` at the `>>>` prompt, what did you get?

Comment: Thanks, Oli. Yes, the matrix is sparse. I'm trying to place the immediate environment of a small robot into a grid and try to determine (using other sensors) if the robot is near the edge of the sidewalk or not.  Does that help?

Comment: S. Lot: Yes, I'm sorry, I do mean a single bit not integer. When I entered 100000000*100000000 into the interpreter, I got 10000000000000000L.

Comment: even if you could store it, you couldn't do anything useful with it. Hard to imagine you would need anything like that size.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, here I agree with you.

Comment: Having an exact answer seems to make your `9.53674316 × 10^9` seem kind of wrong, doesn't it?  Also.  Don't add comments.  Please **update** the question.  Please don't say "single bit integer" since that's meaningless.  Please **update** the question to say "bit".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, an element of {0, 1} should consume at most 1 bit per cell. That means 8 cells per byte or 1192092895 megabytes or about **one petabyte**, which is too much, unless you are google :) Not to mention, even processing (or saving) such matrix would take too much time (about a year I'd say).

You said that in many cases you won't even need matrix so large. So, you can create smaller matrix at start (10,000 x 10,000) and then double the size every time enlargment is needed, copying old contents.

If your **matrix is sparse** (has much much more 1's than 0's or vice-versa), then it is much more efficient to store just coordinates where ones are in some efficient data structure, depending what operations (search, data access) you need.

Side note: In many languages, you have to take proper care for that to be true, for example in C, even if you specify variable as boolean, it still takes one byte, 8 times as much as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have an exabyte of memory laying around. Wow. I definitely shouldn't need that and I doubt the projects eventual goals would need a matrix that large just based on memory requirements and projects I know that do a lot more.

Thank you for the tips. Rethinking our approach now!

Comment: I think you should. As I said, If your matrix is really sparse (has much much more 1's than 0's or vice-versa), then store just the "coordinates" of those elements. Of course, then the access complicates a little, probably yielding something worse than O(1).

Comment: That's a Petabyte, not an exabyte (which would be 3 orders of magnitude more)

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct, assuming a single byte is used to store each boolean, which is what a Numpy array with `dtype=bool` will do.

If you expect that relatively few of the matrix's entries will be one, then consider using a [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) matrix instead; that will only store the ones.

Comment: Thank you! I've had very little experience with scipy so I'll check it out.